# Retrieve real-time entries of m3u8 file (HLS) creating with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, tail, ip-camera

I am using ffmpeg for the recording of rtsp stream from IP camera by generating m3u8 file with ts chunks. I want real time or only latest entries done by ffmpeg in generated m3u8 file but I didn't able to get that.

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.27:80/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 -t 86399 -vcodec copy -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*5) -hls_list_size 0 -r 12 -f segment -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list /tmp/4/del20180105.m3u8 -segment_format ts -y /tmp/4/%Y%m%d%H%M%S.ts
```

When I apply *tail* command on generated m3u8 file like below I am not able to get new entries.

```
tail -f /tmp/4/del20180105.m3u8
```

I thought for every new entry ffmpeg is replacing the whole m3u8 file with new entry. How I can get realtime entries of ts file name and duration from ffmpeg generated m3u8 file?

Comment: If the file is being recreated on changes then inotifywait might be more useful. (tail also has --max-unchanged-stats, but the documentation for that option suggests inotify too..)

Comment: Thank you Digikata I tested it but it is returning whole file on every new entry and I want only new entries not whole file.

Comment: The problem is that tail will follow the old file, or return the whole new file. you might have to run a script to do something like save the old file and diff on inotify update to get the new entries.

Comment: "-hls_list_size 0" should be for example "-hls_list_size 1" for having the last segment.